# Nextjs image value passed as empty FileList to server actions / Zod - Shadcn- React hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

I have simple 2 input form .

When I submit the form, it sucessfully log proper values but after I call my server action and pass the values, server returns empty image value .

Thanks for any help...

useForm & fileRef (image: FileList)

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof newProductSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(newProductSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: '',
      image: undefined,
    },
  });

  const fileRef = form.register('image', { required: true });
```

input

```
 <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name='image'
              render={() => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input type='file' accept='image/*' {...fileRef} />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                   
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
```

onSubmit function

```
    async function onSubmit(values) {
        console.log('a',values); // works
        console.log('b',form.getValues('image')); //works
    
        setPending(true);
        const { success, data, message } = await createNewProductWorkspace(values); // Empty Image
....
```